# I can't connect to the tor network

Tags: help, linux

I downloaded tor but I cant connect to the tor network (I'm using kali linux)

here is the tor log:

02/07/2017 00:44:35.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

02/07/2017 00:44:35.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

02/07/2017 00:44:35.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

02/07/2017 00:44:35.200 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

02/07/2017 00:44:35.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server

02/07/2017 00:44:35.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server

02/07/2017 00:45:07.900 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host 74A910646BCEEFBCD2E874FC1DC997430F968145 at 199.254.238.52:443)

02/07/2017 00:45:07.900 [WARN] 10 connections have failed:

02/07/2017 00:45:07.900 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking 
(TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE

02/07/2017 00:45:54.800 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

02/07/2017 00:45:54.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

02/07/2017 00:45:54.800 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

02/07/2017 00:45:54.800 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.

Comment: This looks like it may be TLS interception censorship, you should try to use bridges with pluggable transports.

Comment: I added bridges but I still get the same problem, the thing is that I've always used tor without any error even on bootable kali, when i installed kali this error occured

Comment: What kind of bridges? Straight Tor bridges won't work, you need to use a pluggable transport like obfs4 in cases where DPI is being used.

Comment: I just opened it again and it worked, haha dk what was the problem